# Receiving duplicate emails with sendEmail()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I tried both `MailApp.sendEmail()` and `GmailApp.sendEmail()` to send an email confirmation from `onFormSubmit` and ending up with multiple duplicate emails (as many as 6). The code looks like this:

```
function sendEmailConf_(ss, email, session) {
  Logger.log("sendEmailConf_ email: %s for session: %s", email, session);
  var formUrl = ss.getFormUrl();             // Use form attached to sheet
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formUrl);
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  Logger.log("Count of form responses: %s", formResponses.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
    if (formResponses[i].getRespondentEmail() == email) {
      Logger.log("Sending email to: %s for session: %s", email, session[0]);
      GmailApp.sendEmail(
        email,
        'Confirmation for registration of: ' + session[0] + ', ' + getSessionSchedStr(session),
        ('Thanks for registering!\n\n' + getResponseAsText(formResponses[i]) + '\n\n' +
               'You may change your response using this URL: ' + formResponses[i].getEditResponseUrl())
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Using script transcript and log statements, I confirmed that `sendEmail()` is getting called only once and that the email is a string with single email address in it. The emails I receive have exactly the same body and are received at the same time and they all have the same from and to addresses (both mine, since I am testing it). Anybody has a clue on what is going wrong here?

Edit: Just observed that the duplicate count is increasing by one every time it is run. I just tried it again and got 7 fresh emails, all exact duplicates (and different from prior 6). I am clueless on what could be causing such a behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the script editor and choose Resources -> Current Project Triggers. Make sure you only have a single trigger associated with the script.

If you have shared the script with multiple users, you'll have to repeat this from the account of every user who may have authorized the script.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! There is this code that gets run as part of `onOpen` and so is adding the trigger again and again: `ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit').forSpreadsheet(ss).onFormSubmit().create()`.